# Convert Dome javascript Object to react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using some library, it's return to me Dom object of html element. 
So I wanna set this dom object to state in reactjs and render to UI like this:

```
this.setState({
  video: videoElement
})
render () {
  return (
         <div>{this.state.video}</div>
         )
       }
```

Because video is not React element. So I got an error:

```
invariant.js:44 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLVideoElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Video`.
```

Are there any way to convert Dom Object to React element?

Comment: What is the structure format for video element?Is it HTML 5 video?

Comment: Right html5 video. This is video stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.state.video` is the video stream,then use the html5 video element in JSX.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <video width="400" controls>
               <source src={this.state.video} type={this.state.video_format} />
           </video>
       </div>
    )
}
```